# Spring Boot + Hibernate + Mysql how to generate class java

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

How to generate java classes from hibernate plugin?

I tried the online guides like these

[How to configure maven hbm2hbmxml and hbm2java to run one after the other in mvn clean install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083727/how-to-configure-maven-hbm2hbmxml-and-hbm2java-to-run-one-after-the-other-in-mvn)

but I can not generate them.

Comment: It'll be good if you post more information, like your `hibernate3-maven-plugin` plugin configuration from pom.xml, `your.reveng.xml`, `your.hibernate.properties`, commands you ran and output with statcktrace if there was an exception.

Comment: I solved thanks to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498174/hbm2java-failedunable-to-load-class-declared-as-mapping-class-com-dss-domain

Answer (score 0):

pom.xml

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>hbm2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <components>
                        <component>
                            <name>hbm2java</name>
                            <implementation>configuration</implementation>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                        </component>
                    </components>
                    <componentProperties>
                        <goal>hbm2java</goal>
                        <revengfile>/src/main/resources/model.reveng.xml</revengfile>
                        <configurationfile>/src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml</configurationfile>
                        <drop>true</drop>
                        <jdk5>true</jdk5>

                    </componentProperties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

model.reveng.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Reverse Engineering DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd" >


<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
<schema-selection match-schema = "my_db" />
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>

hibernate.cfg.xml

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">user</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">pass</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>

        </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

BUILD SUCCESS but in the target folder no class.

Comment: RUN AS -> Maven generate-sources